# Software for displaying multiple time zones

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, time, clock

I need software that could display multiple time zones as I need them. Windows 7 displays 2 time zones but I need more. The software that I need should be freeware first, if not then payable

I need a desktop app and not online as it easy not to open website every now and then

Comment: A Web search for "free multiple time zones" turns up lots of stuff - give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just right-click on your Windows 7 Desktop, choose Gadgets, select the Clock to add it to the desktop, right-click on the clock and choose options, and give it a name like "US Eastern", or "Dusseldorf", and then pick the time zone you want the clock to dislpay from the list.  You can add multiple clocks and configure each one to the time zone you need.